# How to get WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE Permission in Adapter?

Tags: android, android-studio, android-adapter, android-download-manager, download-manager

i want to download image from remote url , and i need to get user persmission to save image, but i am unable to do that in GridAdapter.java file , this is not working in adapter:

```
requestPermissions((Activity) context,new String[]{android.Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE},DOWNLOAD_REQUEST_CODE);
```

i have tried many methods which are available on internet, but nothing seems to work,

like `ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(context,new String[]{android.Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE},DOWNLOAD_REQUEST_CODE);`

```
 requestPermissions((Activity) context.getApplicationContext(),new String[]{android.Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE},DOWNLOAD_REQUEST_CODE);
```

Comment: you can use callbacks for this, and handle callback in activity and call requestPermissions() there.

Comment: how to use callback ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

in GridActivity class create an interface and implements it in GridAdapter class

```
interface IPermissionCallback{
    void askForStoragePermission();
    Boolean checkSelfStoragePermission();
}

public class GridActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements 
    IPermissionCallback {

    private static final int DOWNLOAD_REQUEST_CODE = 1001;
    private GridAdapter adapter;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState, @Nullable 
        PersistableBundle persistentState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState, persistentState);
    
        //other codes...
        //initialize GridAdapter here and then call setPermissionCallback() 
        //method as shown below
        adapter.setPermissionCallback(this);
    }


    @Override
    public void askForStoragePermission() {
        requestPermissions(new String[] 
        {android.Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE},
        DOWNLOAD_REQUEST_CODE);
    }

    @Override
    public Boolean checkSelfStoragePermission() {
    
        if(checkCallingOrSelfPermission(
            android.Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE) == 
            PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED){
                return true;
        }
        return false;
    }


     @Override
     public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, @NonNull String[] 
     permissions, @NonNull int[] grantResults) {
          super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, 
          grantResults);

          if (requestCode == DOWNLOAD_REQUEST_CODE 
          && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED){
               //permission granted update GridAdapter to do next task
               adapter.onPermissionResult(true);
          }else{
               //permission denied update GridAdapter to do next task
               adapter.onPermissionResult(false);
          }
     }
 }
```

and in Grid Adapter you have to write these methods

```
public class GridAdapter/**extends needed classes etc.*/{
     private IPermissionCallback callback;


     public void yourMethodWhereYouDownloadingImg(){
         if (callback != null && callback.checkSelfStoragePermission()){
             //already permission is granted
         }else{
            callback.askForStoragePermission();
         }
     }

     public void setPermissionCallback(IPermissionCallback c){
         this.callback = c;
     }

     public void onPermissionResult(Boolean permissionGranted){
         /**
           * if @permissionGranted is true download image else inform user 
             that permission is denied
           */
     }
}
```

Comment: do i need to create new activity called "GridActivity" ? because there is no such activity

Comment: No. It is a sample code demonstrating how to use callbacks, In your actual code, GridActivity will be the activity/fragment where you are initializing your Grid View and GridAdapter.java

Comment: i am getting this error error: IPermissionCallback is not public in com.punjabidharti.punjabidharticom.activity; cannot be accessed from outside package

Comment: you can create another java file named IPermissionCallback.java and paste `public interface IPermissionCallback{
    void askForStoragePermission();
    Boolean checkSelfStoragePermission();
}`